# Jenkins - add new build statuses

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Does anyone know if there is a way to add new build statuses to Jenkins?  For example, I have a job that checks our build server to see if a new build is available.  I don't want that job to report 'FAILURE', but instead would like to report 'NO NEW BUILD' instead if a new build not available.

Thanks for any suggestions!
Eric

Answer (score 0):

You can't define new "build statuses". But maybe you could use "unstable" (yellow) for this?